# Is there a R code set to use PubMed ID or DOI to get data files for that article, please?

Tags: r, data-files, ncbi, pubmed, doi

I am trying to get the data file names from NCBI or PubMed that are related or attached to hundreds of unique DOIs or PMIDs, in R language.  For example. I have PMID: 19122651 and, I want to get the names of the three GSEs connected to it, which are: GSE12781,GSE12782, and GSE12783.
I have searched various sources and packages to no avail.
Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the [rentrez](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rentrez/) package.

The required function is [entrez_link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rentrez/versions/1.2.1/topics/entrez_link).

Example:

```
library(rentrez)

results <- entrez_link(dbfrom = 'pubmed', id = 19122651, db = 'gds')

results$links$pubmed_gds
[1] "200012783" "200012782" "200012781"
```

The 3 results are the IDs for the associated GEO Dataset records. You can convert them to GSE accessions using `entrez_summary`.

Here's a somewhat ugly `sapply` that may serve as the basis for a function:

```
sapply(results$links$pubmed_gds, function (id) entrez_summary("gds", id)$accession, 
       USE.NAMES = FALSE)

[1] "GSE12783" "GSE12782" "GSE12781"
```

Comment: This is terrific!  Thank you very much.  I have been racking my brain and scouring the internet and none was this simple or straight forward!  Appreciate your time and assistance very much.

Comment: No problem. `rentrez` is a great package, well-worth getting to know. Please accept the answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: @neilfws: you have a typo in the last line of code with `sapply`?  it gives an error with `result$links$pubmed_gds` and probably was meant to be `results$links$pubmed_gds` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can query NCBI via `rentrez` package as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rentrez/vignettes/rentrez_tutorial.html). Function `entrez_link()` should be able to find cross-references